# File upload not working due to lack of permission [PHP]

Tags: php

I have a system where users upload a file such as an image and it gets located in a folder called uploads. This works on my localhost but not when making the website live. It gives me an error that I don't have permission to up or download the content. I think this has to do with not being able to edit the something in the folder since they are not authenitcated with my host and therefore dont have access to changing any files. Anybody who knows what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have access to the location of the files? If so, you can check manually the permissons of the folders that contains those files.

Comment: I have checked so that they can read, write and execute in the folder, but still does not work.

Comment: Have you tried using your FTP Client tool. That normally allows persission amendments

Comment: No I havent, do you think that could work?

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message?

Comment: When downloading: Failed - Forbidden

Comment: You might just need to change the apache site config to allow access to that directory.   Try this http://serverfault.com/questions/46575/apache-authentication-allow-public-access-to-a-subdirectory?rq=1